# Exporting Data from Evernote

Tags: evernote

I am trying to export data from Evernote for a fixed asset report. How can I do that? We currently have all of our equipment in evernote folders and I need to get it into some kind of usable form, e.g. a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Evernote Windows client you can export notes via File -> Export
You can also right click on the Folder or individual Note and select the Export option.

For additional information https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/209005557-How-to-back-up-export-and-restore-import-notes-and-notebooks